# Can I one hot a large dataframe directly as a file?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a bit of experiment and wanted to save a one hot encoded dataframe directly as a file. My Data is very large almost 2 million rows and over 10k unique values so the resulting dataframe is large. If I add the Sparse=True flag then the dataframe is only about 100MB.

This is my current approach(taking over a hour)

```
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(my_DF, columns=['cat'], sparse=True)
one_hot.to_csv("./testOneHot.csv.zip", compression="zip")
```

Not saving the file in compressed format took a long time also(I stopped it at the one hour mark as well).

I've noticed the get.dummies part is fairly quick(less than a min) but saving it to a file takes a ton of time. Because without sparse=true the DF would exceed the memory in my machine I'm trying to save it to a flat file to process in chucks later.

Is there a way to speed this process up and directly save the one hot results directly to a file? Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: 1. Do it in chunks, 2. yes compression is key for io performance, always compress 3. use a proper format, e.g hdf5; personally i prefer to use `h5py` directly instead of pandas io routines which use `ptytables` under the hood 4. maybe think about working directly in numpy, pandas can be quite inefficient at times, but thats just a guess

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann I'm not clear, can you give me a example? I saw the option for chunksizeint when saving the dataframe but does that speed it up? Do you have a sample of the approach(I can tailor it to my problem..just not clear of your approach)

Comment: Sure. What i meant with chunks, is to save the file in a loop, e.g `one_hot = pd.get_dummies(my_DF.iloc[i : i + 100000], ...)`. Doing it that way is relatively memory and cache friendly while still being computational performant. Then for storing e.g with h5py you do `h5_ds[i : i + 100000] = one_hot`. You can find the h5py documentation at https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/ . There are some optimization aspects with regards to hdf5 due to the sparse nature of the data and maybe i will do some benchmarks later if I got time.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Interesting thank you. Saving a sparse data frame to hdf5 is apparently not supported yet in pandas ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462891/getting-sparsedtype-object-has-no-attribute-itemsize-when-trying-to-save-spa/65462969#65462969 ).  How do you save your dataframes to hdf5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is pickle the dataframe

```
df.to_pickle(fileName)
```

then read it back with

```
df = pd.read_pickle(fileName)
```

The real benefit is the load time from a pickle file is much faster than the flat files that I use otherwise.  I also keep them with the suffix `.pkl` so i know what they are but that is just my convention.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to save the file as csv so I can later process it in chucks. Can I do the same for the pickle? I did try it and it saved the file as a 52 mb file in a few seconds!

Comment: Split the dataframe into smaller chunks using np.array_split (although numpy functions are not guaranteed to work, it does now, although there used to be a bug for it).

Then pickle the smaller dataframes.

When you unpickle them use pandas.append or pandas.concat to glue everything back together.

Comment: Chunk usage is great also provided you are no doing global comparisons on larger datasets, like finding means or standard deviations.

Comment: Also reading pickle files are much, much better than reading flat files, pickle is just great at reading.

Comment: Unfortunately, pickle is python-only and the might cause issues even across different python versions (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format). Keep that in mind when working with it.